# Clicking button inside popup window not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a simple popup window which contain label and button, and I want to set a text to the label by clicking the button inside the popup window. I tried doing this but it didn't work and I realized that it only work if I moved the label and button outside the popup window.

button to open popup window:

```
                  <asp:linkbutton ID="Linkbutton1" runat="server"  onclientclick="openPopup()" > open popup window</asp:linkbutton>
```

popup window code:

```
    <div id="popupdiv" title="Basic modal dialog" style="display: none">
    <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  OnClick="change_text"  />


        </div>


 <script type="text/javascript">
 function openPopup() {


     $("#popupdiv").dialog({
         title: "Test",
         width: 290,
         height: 240,
         position: [400, 100],
         modal: true,
         buttons: {
             Close: function () {
                 $(this).dialog('close');
             }
         }
     });
 }
</script>
```

the code behind to run the button inside the popup window:

```
    protected void change_text(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        Label15.Text = "Test";
    }
```

Comment: Is the popup div inside the form tag? If the button inside the dialog is outside the form, I think the server side handler won't fire.

Comment: @jim,  Change your method name change_text or change OnClick="transfer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Change your method name change_text or change OnClick="transfer".

2.) Add appendTo form in jquery.

```
$("#popupdiv").dialog({
         title: "Test",
         width: 290,
         height: 240,
         position: [400, 100],
         modal: true,
         appendTo: "form",
         buttons: {
             Close: function () {
                 $(this).dialog('close');
             }
         }
     });
```

Comment: adding       appendTo: "form",  solved my issue thanks